# CanDeactivate Guard not hiding URL in browser window on cancelling navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router-guards

I am using the skipLocationChange property with true value so I can hide the URL in the browser. It is working fine. But for one of my features, I am using CanDeactivate guard so I can warn the user to save changes before leaving the current page. I am just displaying one pop-up to take confirmation from the user. If the user clicks on "OK" then he is navigating to the target page without any issue also the URL is also hidden in the browser.
But If the user clicks on the "Cancel" button then he is staying on the same page but the problem is here current page URL is getting appended to the base URL in the browser. Which I don't want. I just want the URL to be hidden with the cancel case too.

I am also attaching the link to a sample project created using stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uqq8sg?file=src/app/app.component.html

Steps to produce an issue in sample project:

1. Open the user-details page by clicking on the user-details link.
2. Fill out the user details form and click on the page-one link then it will show a confirmation window click on cancel.
3. User will stay on the same page but it will also append the user-details URL in the browser.

Note: This question [Router guard skip location change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69437273/router-guard-skip-location-change) does not give the answer to my question because that using canActivate guard, not the canDeactivate guard. In canActivate guard we use router.navigateByURL method where we can set skipLocationChange to true value but in canDeactivate guard for canceling navigation we don't use a router.navigateByURL method

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you have set skipLocationChange in routing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Router guard skip location change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69437273/router-guard-skip-location-change)

Comment: @VimalPatel You mean in app.component.html page? It is because I want to hide the url.

Comment: if you want to hide URL then why you are using routing?

Comment: @VimalPatel No that question doesn't answer my question because that using canActivate guard, not the canDeactivate guard. In canActivate guard we use router.navigateByURL method where we can set skipLocationChange to true value but in canDeactivate guard for canceling navigation we don't use router.navigateByURL method

Comment: @VimalPatel I am using routing because my application is big enough so It is more easier or efficient to use routing instead controlling everything using if else or switch conditions the stackblitz link is just a sample that is not the actual application.

Comment: got it, I suggest enabling the routing in that case. Its better UX and so much simple

Comment: @VimalPatel yes If the application is big enough having more than 50 pages then I think we should use routing instead controlling everything using the if and else condition. So do you have any idea why it is appending URL to the browser in canceling case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67715098/4960765)

What I changed:
In the component, return pure value, not observer so in the guard I can use it directly

```
return true; //return of(true)
```

In the guard, navigate by router service instead of just return false/true

```
this.router.navigate([state.url], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

[Forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ymdtz2)